# Angular json, filter unwanted json fields

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an json from backend:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "countries" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Brazil",
      "code" : "BR",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1"
        },
        "country" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1"
        },
        "states" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1/states"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Canada",
      "code" : "CA",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/2"
        },
        "country" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/2"
        },
        "states" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/2/states"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And on frontend, I want to get data according to typescript interface:

```
interface Country {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I have a code which maps above json to interface:

```
 getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CountriesResponse>(this.countriesUrl).pipe(
      map(response => <Country[]>response._embedded.countries)
    )
  }

interface CountriesResponse {
  _embedded: {
    countries: Country[]
  }
}
```

But after mapping method still returns data which is not present in typescript interface Country, I mean _links field.
Please suggest how to avoid it.

I actually found some solution but still thinks it could be done better:

```
  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CountriesResponse>(this.countriesUrl).pipe(
      map(response => {
        const data: Country[] = response._embedded.countries
        return data.map(c => ({
          id: c.id,
          name: c.name,
          code: c.code
        }))
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime, all `<Country[]>` does is _assert_ to the compiler that the type of the object is an array of countries (which presumably is also what `CountriesResponse` said). It doesn't really matter that those additional properties exist on the object at runtime, because they can't be accessed through the `Country` interface anyway.

Comment: They accessed if use JSON.strigify(country) it shows those fields, but as your answer if it doesn't really matter, that's ok, thanks

Comment: As mentioned above by @jonrsharpe, typescript doesnt run at run time, the type assertion doesnt help map or transform your API response to your desired interface structure. To Achieve that you would ultimately have to map it.

Now the better way to do it is pretty subjective, I personally like to write a serializer/utility function to map all my API calls to the desired structure. This allows me to process CountriesResponse to Country repeatedly at multiple places.